# hiding div blocks jQuery by range input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an problem but don't understand what is wrong.

```js
function fun1() {
  var rng = $('#r1').val(); //rng - это Input
  $('#one').text(rng);
  jQuery.each($('.content'), function(i, val) {
    if ($(this).text() < rng) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100000" id="r1" oninput="fun1()" />
<p id="one"></p>

<div class="content">2345</div>
<div class="content">85552</div>
<div class="content">2345</div>
<div class="content">25345</div>
<div class="content">123</div>
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">852524</div>
<div class="content">22</div>
```

Program should comparing numbers in contents  with range  at input range. But in the output unhiding even those divs which is greater then  range.
I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: check by converting the div text into integer like this `if(parseInt($(this).text()) <rng){}`

Comment: numbers vs strings

Comment: big thanks now it working

Comment: Yup @PlugPlay, I have added the comment as an answer with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
function fun1() {
  var rng = parseInt($('#r1').val()); //rng - это Input
  $('#one').text(rng);
  jQuery.each($('.content'),function(i,val){
    if(parseInt($(this).text()) < rng){
      $(this).show();
    } else{   
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.content{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max ="100000" id="r1" oninput="fun1()" />
<p id="one"></p>

<div class ="content">2345</div>
<div class ="content">85552</div>
<div class ="content">2345</div>
<div class ="content">25345</div>
<div class ="content">123</div>
<div class ="content">1</div>
<div class ="content">852524</div>
<div class ="content">22</div>
```

Only change in the code is inside `if statement`

`$(this).text()` will return string & so use parseInt whenever you are trying to retrieve valie.

**Code changed**

`var rng = parseInt($('#r1').val());`

`if(parseInt($(this).text()) < rng){`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you haven't parsed the `divs` content and the `range` value, so it was read as `string` instead of `number`, so it was a `string` comparison, that's why you didn't got desired results.

Use `parseInt()` to parse them into a `number` in your code:

```
function fun1() {
  var rng= parseInt($('#r1').val());

  $('#one').text(rng);
  jQuery.each($('.content'),function(i,val){
    if(parseInt($(this).text()) < rng){
      $(this).show();
    } else{   
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function fun1() {
  var rng= parseInt($('#r1').val());
  
  $('#one').text(rng);
  jQuery.each($('.content'),function(i,val){
    if(parseInt($(this).text()) < rng){
      $(this).show();
    } else{   
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.content{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max ="100000" id="r1" oninput="fun1()" />
<p id="one"></p>

<div class ="content">2345</div>
<div class ="content">85552</div>
<div class ="content">2345</div>
<div class ="content">25345</div>
<div class ="content">123</div>
<div class ="content">1</div>
<div class ="content">852524</div>
<div class ="content">22</div>
```